# Your judgement for the afterlife

Tags: wordplay

You have not been the best person during your time on Earth. Your judgement is as such:

> uryy

But what does this mean?

Comment: For future reference, [cryptic-clues] refers to a particular type of crossword clue, not just any "clue" that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means

> "rot in hell", because this is a ROT13 encoding of the word `hell`.

Comment: ... which is ironically reversed...

Answer (score 15):

Alternative possibility

> "You are too wise"
>  Read literally from **u r 2ys**, because perhaps it's smart not to be the best person.

Comment: I had to upvote this even though it was not the intended answer. What are the odds such a short riddle has multiple solutions?

Comment: I think shorter riddles are actually more likely as the clues give fewer constraints and are expanded into more meaning than else.